# How to put jquery noconflict?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery, I am having this problem to add $jq into the script,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#slider').slideshow();
    });

    </script>
```

How to add the $jq inside the script?

Comment: Why are you loading 2 jQuery libraries?

Comment: I got a slider and a navigation both uses different libraries.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#slider').slideshow();
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and include only one jquery in page. your script is using two jquery script files, `js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and `js/jquery-1.4.2.js`. remove `js/jquery-1.4.2.js` script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

    $jq(window).load(function(){
        $jq ('#slider').slideshow();
    });

</script
```

Comment: Well, the slide should working smoothly, even though the slide is viewable but not smooth, the slides are like mixed up with big and small pictures. I have checked my slide pictures and settings, no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var $jq = $.noConflict();
    $jq(window).load(function(){
        $jq('#slider').slideshow();
    });

    </script>
```